# Windows actives users logged locked or in sleep mode

Tags: windows, sleep, locked

I would like to create a batch that could list every users "alive" in Windows. Our system accept 5 users connected in the same time on a PC. The active user logged I know how to do that with wmic get username. But how can I list the users in sleeping mode or or just locked ? So, in fact every profiles that are not closed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that:

C:\Windows\System32\tasklist /s computer /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe" /v > c:\windows\temp\tmpfile.txt

for /F "skip=3 tokens=6 delims= " %%G in (c:\Windows\Temp\tmpfile.txt) do @echo %%G